# Find with grep in terminal last hit in log file

Tags: gaussian, programming

I use `grep` to find the string `"Converged?"` with the terminal in several folders to read the output from my gaussian calculations.

My command is

`grep -r -i -A4 Converged?`

What I get as output is in minimal example this:

```
start_struc.log:         Item               Value     Threshold  Converged?
start_struc.log- Maximum Force            0.000022     0.000450     YES
start_struc.log- RMS     Force            0.000005     0.000300     YES
start_struc.log- Maximum Displacement     0.010813     0.001800     NO 
start_struc.log- RMS     Displacement     0.002734     0.001200     NO 
--
start_struc.log:         Item               Value     Threshold  Converged?
start_struc.log- Maximum Force            0.000001     0.000450     YES
start_struc.log- RMS     Force            0.000000     0.000300     YES
start_struc.log- Maximum Displacement     0.001210     0.001800     YES
start_struc.log- RMS     Displacement     0.000312     0.001200     YES
```

But I just want the last time grep finds `Converged?` with the next four Lines.
I looked up different internet forums and the manual of grep but I think I did not find  a flag I can use. Because the problem is, I get up to 50 hits before and I don't want to print them out in terminal.
Has someone an idea or search for the convergence the same way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this requires [piping](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/), see these [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/197123) or [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24014194/7492468) questions. For a single file, the two main approaches would be using `tail` or `tac`. I tend to use the `tail` approach most myself, as I find it easier to remember or to just slap onto the end of a preceding grep statement.

- `grep -i -A4 Converged? file | tail`

will print the last 10 lines from grep's output. To specify it further, make it print only the last 5 lines corresponding to the last entry:

`grep -i -A4 Converged? file | tail -n 5`

- Alternatively, use `tac` to "`cat`" a file backwards, and then `grep -m 1` to print only the first match:

`tac file | grep -i -m 1 -B4 Converged? | tac`

Again, `tac` outputs the file backwards so we need to use -B4 instead of -A4 to get the additional lines. The final pipe to `tac` reverses the line order again, to match that in the file.

- To do this for many files, you can use a `for` loop, either in a shell script or as a one-liner:

`for a in files; do tac $a | grep -i -B4 -m 1 Converged? | tac; done`

where you need to replace "files" by an appropriate path to the different files.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Ex.

```
ex file <<< '?Converged?,+4p'
```

Or to print until the end of the file instead of just 4 lines,

```
ex file <<< '?Converged?,$p'
```